# css3 transition start on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a CSS3 transition to start after click.

Now it works fine if the element gets added a class with jQuery (see `span.toggle-nav.two`) which knows then what to do.

I've tried with `:focus` (see `span.toggle-nav.one`) but that doesn't work. How can I make it work without jQuery?

Please have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/aE4C7/ clicking on `Two` works but clicking on `One` does not.

```
<span class="toggle-nav one">One</span>
<span class="toggle-nav two">Two</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.toggle-nav.two').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass("click");
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.toggle-nav {
    background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8hRiDDs6RJRzelpuFRX2wG5Wx2cQPOBWKYCOmlA2Wr34dx1vv);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:50px;height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.toggle-nav.one:focus {
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
}
.toggle-nav.two.click {
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;    
}


@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% { -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
</style>
```

Is there a way to make this work without jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let `span` getting focus, you need to set `tabindex` attribute:

```
<span class="toggle-nav one" tabindex="-1">One</span>
```

Then you could wish for styling to set CSS outline property too:

`outline: none;`

### DEMO

Comment: is there a way to use the animation multiple times using tabindex? I changed the transition from infinite to one http://jsfiddle.net/aE4C7/7/ could I run the animation again if I click again?

Comment: You could use onanimationend event to blur element but then this invoke javascript/jQuery, not sure it is what you are looking for

Comment: Kinda but then I think I'm better of using the add/remove Class. I thought I'm really doing something wrong and there must be an easy way to turn the animation on and off. That's actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this using **purely CSS** - The only way to correctly simulate click events in CSS is to fake it with a checkbox, otherwise using `:active` or `:focus` will stop any applied transition or animation as soon as the element loses focus, not when it is clicked on again.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZxKJ6/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <input id='box' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='box'>Click Me!</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
}
label {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background:white;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    opacity:0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    -webkit-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin 0.6s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```